# Is $f(b) = \max\{c^T x \mid Ax\leq \sqrt{b} \}$ convex, concave, or is it not possible to say?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am completely stuck on the following problem:

For $b\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$, we write $\sqrt{b}$ to be the vector of square roots componentwise, i.e. $(\sqrt{b})_i = \sqrt{b_i}$ for $i\in \{1, \dots, n\}$.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as:
$$ f(b) = \max \{c^T x \mid Ax \leq \sqrt{b} \} $$
where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n×d}$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Is $f$ convex, concave, or is it not possible in general to say if $f$ is convex or concave? Prove your result.

The following fact is given and allowed to be assumed: Let $w\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$. Then the function $g^w(b) := \sqrt{b}^T w $ is a concave function in $b$.

I believe that it is neither convex nor concave, but have no idea how to show it (or even if it is indeed true)

Edit: It would seem the problem is not well-defined. However, I believe what they are getting at is the following question: is it ever possible that $f$ could be convex? We know it could be concave (for instance in the case of $f(b) = \sup\{x \mid x\leq \sqrt{b}\}$). Or is it impossible for $f$ to ever to convex?

Comment: Is $d$ fixed prior to the maximum, or is the $\max$ allowed to vary $d$?

Comment: Is $A$ fixed prior to the maximum, or is the $\max$ allowed to vary $A$?

Comment: @EricTowers I believe both A and d are fixed before the maximum

Comment: It is not clear to me that it is well defined, $\sup\{ -x | x \le \sqrt{b} \} = +\infty$, and certainly concavity is a possibility, $f(b) = \sup\{ x | x \le \sqrt{b} \} = \sqrt{b}$ is concave.

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed I would agree that concavity is possible, but is is always possible? That I am unsure of.

Comment: It is not terribly well defined, if $c$ is not orthogonal to $\ker A$ then the value is $+\infty$.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't seem well defined. However I believe what they are getting at is the following question: is it ever possible that $f$ could be convex? We know it could be concave (for instance in the case of $f(b) = sup\{x \mid x\leq \sqrt{b}\}$). Or is it impossible for $f$ to ever to convex?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you could take $c=0$ and get $f=0$ which is trivially convex.

Comment: the fact that $f$ takes values in the extended reals isn't an issue. This is generally okay for convexity / concavity by using the convention that $\infty > x$ and $-\infty < x$ for all $x$ in the extended reals and that $c \cdot \pm \infty = \pm \infty$ for $c \geq 0$.

Comment: oh, actually this can be an issue if $f$ is allowed to take $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. I wrote about this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Suppose $f$ is well defined (that is, finite and a maximiser exists) on $[b_1,b_2]$, the convex hull of $b_1,b_2$. Then $f$ is concave on $[b_1,b_2]$. There are $x_1,x_2$ such that
$f(b_k) = c^T x_k, Ax_k \le \sqrt{b_k}$.

Suppose $t \in [0,1]$. Then $A(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le t\sqrt{b_1}+(1-t)\sqrt{b_2} \le \sqrt{tb_1+(1-t)b_2}$ (componentwise) and so
$f(tb_1+(1-t)b_2)  \ge c^T(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)=tf(b_1)+(1-t)f(b_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: The function $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$
f(b) = \max \{ c^T x \mid A x \leq b \}
$
is concave.

Let's set up some notation.
Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$ be given and consider $b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb{R}_+$.
Let the convex combination be denoted by $b_\lambda = \lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda) b_1$.
Let two (arbitrary) optimal solutions be denoted as $x_i \in \text{argmax} \{ c^T x \mid A x \leq b_i \}$ for $i =1,2$.
Note that by construction, $f(b_0) = c^T x_0$ and $f(b_1) = c^T x_1$.

**Lemma**: The point $x_\lambda = \lambda x_0 + (1-\lambda) x_1$ satisfies the system of equations $A x_\lambda \leq \sqrt{b_\lambda}$.

**Proof**: Observe that
\begin{align}
A x_\lambda 
&= A(\lambda x_0 + (1-\lambda) x_1)
&(\text{definition of $x_\lambda$}) \\
&= \lambda A x_0 + (1-\lambda) A x_1 
&(\text{linearity}) \\
&\leq \lambda \sqrt{b_0} + (1-\lambda) \sqrt{b_1}
&(\text{because $x_0$ and $x_1$ are feasible.}) \\
&\leq \sqrt{\lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda) b_1} 
&(\dagger)\\
&= \sqrt{b_\lambda} 
\enspace,
\end{align}
where the inequality $(\dagger)$ follows from the hint that you were given. $\blacksquare$

Now, we can proceed to prove the main claim.

**Proof** (of main claim): Observe that

\begin{align}
f(b_\lambda) 
&= \max \{ c^T x \mid A x \leq b_\lambda \} \\
&\geq c^T x_\lambda 
&(\text{lemma above})\\
&= c^T (\lambda x_0 + (1-\lambda) x_1) 
&(\text{definition of $x_\lambda$})\\
&= \lambda c^T x_0 + (1-\lambda) c^T x_1 
&(\text{linearity of the objective})\\
&= \lambda \cdot f(b_0) + (1-\lambda) \cdot f(b_1). 
&(\text{choice of $x_0$ and $x_1$})\\
\end{align}

Note that the proof extends to the setting where the objective is concave (as opposed to just linear).

---

**EDIT**

Here is how to deal with the issue of unboundedness of the linear program.
Suppose that if $b$ yields an unbounded program (i.e. $\sup \{ c^T x \mid A x \leq \sqrt{b} \} = \infty$), we set $f(b) = - \infty$.
This is perhaps counter-intuitive, but let me argue that this is the "right" thing to do.
Suppose that $b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ are given, with $b_\lambda \triangleq \lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda) b_1$.
We seek to show $f(b_\lambda) \geq \lambda f(b_0) + (1-\lambda) f(b_1)$.
Suppose that $b_1$ yields an unbounded program so that $f(b_1) = -\infty$.
Then, concavity follows as
$$
\lambda f(b_0) + (1-\lambda) f(b_1)
= - \infty 
\leq f(b_\lambda)
$$
which holds regardless of the value of $f(b_\lambda)$.

Comment: $x=0$ always satisfies the constraint, so it is always true that $f(b) \ge 0$. There is no infeasibility issue.

Comment: good point - thanks! I've updated my answer. If you define $f(b) = -\infty$ for $b$ yielding an unbounded program (i.e. $sup \{ c^T x \mid A x \leq \sqrt{b} \} = \infty$), then everything works out.

Comment: I do not understand what unbounded $b$ means here.

Comment: Whoops! just a mistake from being tired. I meant that $b$ yields an unbounded program (see edited comment + answer above)